# Переписать фрагмент if / then применяя форму elsif

Tags: операторы, псевдокод

помогите пожалуйста переписать следующий фрагмент программы так, чтобы вложенные if операторы не размещались внутри then-частей внешних if-операторов. Вместо этого примените форму elsif.

```
if n >= 60 then
    if n < 80 then
          if n >= 70 then seventy (n)
          else sixty (n)
          end
    else eighty (n)
    end
else twenty (n)
end
```

Comment: тут не благотворительный центр где решают задачи для школьников. Что Вы сами пытались сделать? И о каком языке Вы спрашивает? или Вы перечислили все какие вспомнили?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
if n >= 80 then
    eighty (n)
elif n >= 70 then
    seventy (n)
elif n >= 60 then
    sixty (n)
else
    twenty (n)
end
```

Это - для непонятливых - *псевдокод*, наиболее близкий к форме кода, приведенного в вопросе. Переводить на конкретный язык - дело автора вопроса, раз он не указал, на каком именно языке ему написать код :)

Comment: причем тут C# ?

Comment: @OXYGEN Теги стоят - C#, Python, C, Pascal... и т.д. Я вообще дал **псевдокод**, если кто не понял. А уж на какой язык его ТС переведет - его дело :)

Comment: Собственно в этом вопрос и был, это контрольный из книги Теория и практика  языков программирования, спасибо